# Why is betting on yourself in a sporting event considered unethical?

Tags: rules, betting

I understand all the problems that a sports player betting against themselves can cause, but what is the harm caused by betting for oneself or one's team to win  (note I am not saying win by X points, just win).

In players contracts, they could have clauses for getting X money with each win, how would this be different than a player putting X money on a game, and winning if they win?

Note:  The reason I am just saying winning is because if something such as winning by X points was done, the player would be trying for that goal, compared to the goal of winning (which would be the same goal even if he was not betting)

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't being on yourself to win - it's on the matches when you *don't* bet on yourself. Consider a situation where I bet on myself to win in 9 out of 10 matches, but then didn't bet on the 10th match. Am I going to try quite as hard, knowing that I'm (effectively) getting paid less for a win?

Answer (score 4):

First for NFL, MLB, NCAA, NBA, and other US sports entities it is outlawed because of player's involvements with bookies and betting rings.  MLB isn't worried about a pitcher that wants to bet on himself against a bad team.  MLB is afraid that the pitcher will make relationships with bookies, could possibly lose money, and then play differently or provide inside information to pay off debts.

With team sports in general it isn't about betting on yourself or why didn't you bet on yourself, it is just the hovering cloud of impropriety too.  For instance Pete Rose bet on his team many many times.  When he was a manager did he overuse his bullpen to gain a win on bet day?

Second point is that players can bet on themselves in some sports.  Depending on the country you are in it can be legal to wager on yourself on tennis (heard many players doing this on tour), golf, and boxing - and I am sure there are many more.

Answer (score -1):

I partially agree with you. But I think they're not allowed to because people would watch and see when they DON'T bet on themselves to win. Then of course  that would be noticed by everyone making bets and mess with the gambling world, plus it's suspicious when you don't bet on yourself. That could definitely be used as evidence in court of someone shaving points on a game or throwing it. "Your honor. He bet on himself every single game except this one. And this is the 1 game he lost." That looks extremely suspicious.